Twilio automated calls with Node.js backend, calls always "complete"
I'm having an issue with my Node.js server that automates my Twilio calls. I'm trying to update a Monday.com status based on call actions; however, when I hangup the call or don't answer, the callStatus endpoint is called with a complete status, which isn't true. Within Twilio's documentation, there are final call statuses (no-answer, complete, failed, and canceled), I just can't figure out how to get Twilio to send these to my endpoint.
I think it has to have something to do with my /initiateCall endpoint. This receives a contactName; if it was set in the call, it means we already have their name. Otherwise, the call needs to collect that data by calling the /askName endpoint.
As a side-note, I'm using Google TTS to synthesize a more natural sounding voice. That's what the .play() calls are using.
router.post('/initiateCall', async (req, res) => {
    const { text, to, contactName, pulseId, linkedPulseId } = req.body;

    console.log('Request:', req.body);

    if (!text || !to) {
        return res
            .status(400)
            .send('Please provide both "text" and "to" in the request body.');
    }

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/googleTTS/synthesize`, {
            text: text,
        });

        const audioUrl = response.data.url;
        console.log('audioUrl:', audioUrl);

        const twiml = new twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

        if (contactName) {
            twiml.play(audioUrl);
            twiml.pause({ length: 1 }); // Optional pause for effect
        } else {
            twiml.play(audioUrl);
            twiml.pause({ length: 1 });
            twiml.redirect(`${baseUrl}/twilio/askName`);
        }

        const call = await client.calls.create({
            from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
            to: to,
            twiml: twiml.toString(),
            statusCallback: `${baseUrl}/twilio/callStatus?pulseId=${pulseId}&linkedPulseId=${linkedPulseId}`,
            statusCallbackEvent: [
                'initiated',
                'ringing',
                'answered',
                'completed',
                'no-answer',
                'busy',
                'failed',
                'canceled',
            ],
        });

        res.send({ message: 'Call initiated successfully', callSid: call.sid });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during call initiation:', error.message);
        res.status(500).send('Failed to initiate call.');
    }
});

The /askName route is below.
router.post('/askName', async (req, res) => {
    const twiml = new twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    const retry = req.query.retry;

    if (req.body.CallStatus && req.body.CallStatus !== 'in-progress') {
        twiml.hangup();
        res.type('text/xml');
        res.send(twiml.toString());
        return;
    }

    twiml
        .gather({
            input: 'speech',
            action: '/twilio/confirmName',
            method: 'POST',
            speechTimeout: '2',
            language: 'en-US',
        })
        .play(
            retry ? `${awsS3Url}/askNameRetry.wav` : `${awsS3Url}/askName.wav`
        );

    twiml.redirect('/twilio/askName?retry=true');

    res.type('text/xml');
    res.send(twiml.toString());
});

I added a check for CallStatus. Within the Twilio logs, I noticed that it was being called, despite the call never even being picked up (I hang up during the call).
Then I try to handle the statuses with my /callStatus:
router.post('/callStatus', async (req, res) => {
    const callStatus = req.body.CallStatus;
    const callSid = req.body.CallSid;
    const pulseId = req.query.pulseId;
    const linkedPulseId = req.query.linkedPulseId;
    const exitedCall = exitedCalls.get(callSid);

    console.log('Received Call Status:', callStatus);
    console.log('Call SID:', callSid);
    console.log('Call Request Body:', req.body);

    if (pulseId && linkedPulseId) {
        try {
            let statusText;

            if (
                ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'in-progress'].includes(
                    callStatus
                )
            ) {
                statusText = `In Progress: ${callStatus}`;
            } else {
                switch (callStatus) {
                    case 'completed':
                        const recognizedName = recognizedNames.get(callSid);
                        if (recognizedName) {
                            await mondayService.updateMondayContactName(
                                pulseId,
                                recognizedName
                            );
                            statusText = 'Completed: Name Received';
                        } else if (exitedCall) {
                            statusText = 'Completed: Call Exited';
                        } else {
                            statusText = 'Completed';
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'no-answer':
                        statusText = 'Incomplete: No Answer';
                        break;
                    case 'busy':
                        statusText = 'Incomplete: Busy';
                        break;
                    case 'failed':
                        statusText = 'Incomplete: Failed';
                        break;
                    case 'canceled':
                        statusText = 'Incomplete: Canceled';
                        break;
                    default:
                        statusText = 'Unknown Call Completion Status';
                }
            }

            await mondayService.updateCallStatus(linkedPulseId, statusText);
            console.log(`Call status updated to: ${statusText}`);

            if (
                [
                    'completed',
                    'no-answer',
                    'busy',
                    'failed',
                    'canceled',
                ].includes(callStatus)
            ) {
                recognizedNames.delete(callSid);
                exitedCalls.delete(callSid);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(
                'Error updating call status on Monday.com:',
                error.message
            );
            await mondayService.updateCallStatus(
                linkedPulseId,
                'Update Status Error'
            );
        }
    } else {
        console.log(
            'Missing linkedPulseId or pulseId, cannot update Monday.com'
        );
    }

    res.status(200).send('Call status received and processed.');
});

I can never get the callStatus to have a failed, incomplete status.
I'm not really sure where to go from here. I've been testing and playing around with it for most of the day. Any thoughts?
I tried using <Dial> (twiml.dial()), but I think that's just used to connect an external call -- or I'm way off with interpreting the documentation. I was using it to include a /finalStatus endpoint to see if that would be called. I separated out the completion and in-progress statuses while using that, but the endpoint was never called at all, despite being accessible on the server.

I think the real issue I'm having is that Twilio can't detect if it's a voicemail or not when I end the call, so it assumes it's a real person and just keeps going. I've tried using the asyncAmd function, but it's slow to detect the machine. So, by the time "handleCall" comes around (my new URL for call creation, I got rid of the twiml string), there's no way for me to check it.
